# Why in triangular ABC, AB=BC

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

In the following diagram $B_1=B_2$ and DB||CE. Why $AB=BC$[image]

Comment: It seems false.

Comment: Maybe because ABC is an equilateral triangle...

Comment: My teacher gave it, I tried to use angels and thales-theorem, but  didn't work

Comment: DB seems perpendicular to the base... If so, we have two triangles with all angles equal and one side equal. Thus, apply ASA rule for congruence.

Answer (score 2):

Since $DB\parallel EC$, we have
$$\angle BEC=\angle B_1=\angle B_2=\angle BCE.$$
Thus, $\triangle BCE$ is isosceles triangle and moreover $\triangle BCE$ is similar to $\triangle BAC$. So, we have equality of the ratios of the lengths of the corresponding sides
$$\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{BC}{BE}=1.$$
$\textbf{We have proved, that } AB=BC$.

By the way, since we got that $AB=BC=BE$, we have $\angle ACE=90^{\circ}$. Moreover,
$$\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{BC}{BE}=\frac{AC}{CE}=1.$$
Hence, $\triangle ACE$ is isosceles right triangle.